# How to show the output of selenium webdriver with java on an static html webpage?

Tags: java, html, selenium

How to show the output of selenium webdriver with java on an static html webpage?
How can i save the output to show it on a html page in the form of a table?

Comment: your question is too vague

Answer (score 1):

We use use JQuery to post the result in a specific data file and then manage fetching the data from the file in html

Answer (score 0):

In case if you don't want to use any external jars, let us make it simple. 
1. Generate a new HTML file through the script before starting the script

`FileWriter outputFile = new FileWriter("output.html");
outputFile.write("<html><body><table><th><td>Test Case No</td><td>Result</td></th>")
.
//selenium code
.
.
.`

2. Append your result to this outputFile created.

`outputFile.write("<tr><td>Testcase1</td><td>PASS</td>")
outputFile.write("<tr><td>Testcase2</td><td>PASS</td>")
outputFile.write("<tr><td>Testcase3</td><td>PASS</td>")
outputFile.write("<tr><td>Testcase4</td><td>PASS</td>")`

3. When you are done with your script just add the closing tags of HTML.

   `outputFile.write("</table></body></html>")
   outputFile.close`

This looks simple and easy to do. When we open the file we contain the static HTML page with results posted in table format.

Comment: i am unable to write in the file.